# How I can get timespan from the datetime column based on work type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with datetime of the input and also the input type
I need to get HH:mm duration based on 'Work' until 'Pause'
Then to get 'Pause' duration until next 'Work'

```
ClickEvent              TypeOfWork
----------------------------------
2021-03-09 19:50:30.560 Work
2021-03-09 19:50:41.793 Work
2021-03-09 19:50:52.780 Pause
2021-03-09 19:51:00.840 Work
2021-03-09 19:51:24.640 Work
2021-03-09 19:51:25.973 Work
2021-03-09 19:51:26.387 Work
2021-03-09 19:51:26.710 Work
2021-03-09 19:51:27.327 Work
2021-03-09 19:51:27.933 Work
2021-03-09 19:51:33.827 Work
2021-03-09 19:53:57.443 Work
2021-03-09 19:53:58.557 Work
2021-03-09 19:53:59.133 Work
```

So my output should be:

```
Work           Pause
---------------------------------
00:03          00:00
```

Comment: Can you post sample data as text, preferably as `insert` statements. Explain your data more - in your image "pause" starts at 19:50:52, the next "work" starts at 19:51:00,that's 8 seconds later, so where does 10 minutes arise from?

Comment: I put the output as an example. So i'm not interested in seconds. For example if you have pause after sum more that 60 seconds it will show 00:01. Depends how many pause and work you will have. I just need the output from the example even if there are no hours and minutes after sum

Comment: I understand that, but your required output does not match your example data, the difference is only 8 seconds between the pause event and the next work event, so should that be 00:00? When do you round seconds down or up? How can you expect someone to answer your question if your sample data doesn't make sense?

Comment: also you have not tagged your specific RDBMS

Comment: Actually it can be sum by secods. Even if there are no enough to make the output like 00:01 for example. So i'll show then like 00:00 then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

First a CTE to simplify the problem by identifying where each type of work changes, resetting a row count on each change.

Then using only the rows from this with a rownumber of 1, calculate the difference between the current and next clickevent.

You could stop here to show the time spent sequentially in each block of click events, however finally wrap this in an outer sum to give a total time spent for each TypeOfWork.

Your sample data (in your original image before you changed it) showed multiple TypesOfWork (eg work/pause/stop...) so I've left the output as rows not columns, up to you if you need to pivot it further, but this will give the totals for each specific "TypeOfWork".

```
;with r as (
select TypeOfWork,ClickEvent,Row_Number() over (partition by TypeOfWork,rn - rnDiff order by rn) RowNum 
    from (
        select TypeOfWork, ClickEvent,
            Row_Number() over (order by ClickEvent asc) rn ,Row_Number() over (partition by TypeOfWork order by ClickEvent asc) rnDiff
        from [Table]
    )a
)

select TypeOfWork, Convert(varchar, DateAdd(ss,Sum(EventTot), 0), 114) Duration
from (
    select TypeOfWork, ClickEvent,
        DateDiff(ss, ClickEvent, Lead(ClickEvent,1) over(order by ClickEvent)) EventTot
    from r
    where RowNum=1
)c
group by TypeOfWork
```